# Bootloader doesn't show other OS post-install of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, solaris

So I just have a weird error that I think is associated with Ubuntu's bootloader not recognizing Solaris. What happened was I installed Solaris 11, and then installed Ubuntu alongside, and when I partitioned the drive there was X GB used (for Solaris), and then Y GB free or whatever, but in the X GB used, it said "unknown". After the installation (13.04 if that's relevant), my ability to boot Solaris has been gone, but I know it's still on the disk. The menu simply never appears when I boot up the machine; it simply boots Ubuntu immediately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that grub2's os-prober reads the Solaris file system or its boot loader. Grub does have .mod files for many file systems and if you add the correct driver (if one) you may get it to work.

You may be able to just chain load to the Solaris install.
 Adjust for your drive & partition number (hdX,Y).

```
menuentry "Solaris 11 {
    set root='(hd1,2)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

There are ufs.mod  and xfs.mod files in grub, you may need those like this before the set root.

```
insmod ufs
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to re-install the grub again.

Boot into Ubuntu and follow the steps in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

It will open boot-repair.

See here for more info: [Using Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

If your Solaris is still present then Boot-repair will be able to help you list it back.